# Perl Regular Expression Details

Tags: regex, perl

There is a line `$line =~ s/\^M $//` in a perl code. What does the regex `s/\^M $//` mean?

Comment: It looks like an attempt to remove ^M (Control-M, also know as carriage return, \r) from the end of line, i.e. converting DOS line endings to Unix line endings. But are you sure the ^M are not display artefacts of your terminal or editor? Also, the extra space character looks like it would get in the way of that purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means if `$line` contains the exact sub string `^M` (hat-emm-space) at the end then remove it

The reason for the initial backslash is that `^` has a special meaning in regexp and the backslash turns off the special meaning and makes it literally match

The $ is an anchor to force a match at the end of the line

Often ^M literal characters end up in files when copy paste is inappropriately used

Comment: ***"Often ^M literal characters end up in files when copy paste is inappropriately used"*** That's an excellent point.